# Composer autoload shows content of PHP file instead execute it

Tags: php, composer-php

I have in my composer.json an autoload file:

```
"autoload":{
    "files":[
        "vendor/foo/bar.php"
    ]
},
```

When I run the command line "composer install", after download all packages, it just shows the content of "vendor/foo/bar.php" file insteat execute it. I have no clue about how to solve that.

Comment: How are you opening the page in the browser? Does if start `http://` or `file:///`

Comment: The problem was the short tags, like the first comment in the duplicated question. Tks!